# Unable to upload to Arduino Uno From Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi, reset, upload

I am trying to upload code to my Arduino Uno from my Raspberry Pi 3B+ and have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAM2S27FWAI) guide.

After following the instructions and trying to upload, I received this error message.

```
pi@Positron-Pi:~/sketchbook $ make upload
-------------------------
Arduino.mk Configuration:
- [AUTODETECTED]       CURRENT_OS = LINUX 
- [USER]               ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino 
- [COMPUTED]           ARDMK_DIR = /usr/share/arduino (relative to Common.mk)
- [AUTODETECTED]       ARDUINO_VERSION = 105 
- [DEFAULT]            ARCHITECTURE =  
- [DEFAULT]            ARDMK_VENDOR = arduino 
- [DEFAULT]            ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK = /home/pi/sketchbook 
- [BUNDLED]            AVR_TOOLS_DIR = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr (in Arduino distribution)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDUINO_LIB_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/libraries (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDUINO_VAR_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino//variants (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [COMPUTED]           BOARDS_TXT = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino//boards.txt (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [USER]               USER_LIB_PATH = /home/pi/sketchbook/libraries 
- [DEFAULT]            PRE_BUILD_HOOK = pre-build-hook.sh 
- [USER]               BOARD_TAG = uno 
- [COMPUTED]           CORE = arduino (from build.core)
- [COMPUTED]           VARIANT = standard (from build.variant)
- [COMPUTED]           OBJDIR = build-uno (from BOARD_TAG)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDUINO_CORE_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino//cores/arduino (from ARDUINO_DIR, BOARD_TAG and boards.txt)
- [DETECTED]           MONITOR_BAUDRATE = 9600  (in sketch)
- [DEFAULT]            OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = s 
- [DEFAULT]            MCU_FLAG_NAME = mmcu 
- [DEFAULT]            CFLAGS_STD = -std=gnu11 -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects 
- [DEFAULT]            CXXFLAGS_STD = -std=gnu++11 -fno-threadsafe-statics -flto 
- [COMPUTED]           DEVICE_PATH = /dev/tty* (from MONITOR_PORT)
- [DEFAULT]            FORCE_MONITOR_PORT =  
- [AUTODETECTED]       Size utility: AVR-aware for enhanced output
- [COMPUTED]           BOOTLOADER_PARENT = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino//bootloaders (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDMK_VERSION = 1.5 
- [COMPUTED]           CC_VERSION = 5.4.0 (avr-gcc)
-------------------------
mkdir -p build-uno
make reset
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/sketchbook'
/usr/bin/ard-reset-arduino  /dev/tty36
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ard-reset-arduino", line 45, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial(args.port[0], 115200)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 13] could not open port /dev/tty36: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/tty36'
/usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk:1478: recipe for target 'reset' failed
make[1]: *** [reset] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/sketchbook'
/usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk:1454: recipe for target 'upload' failed
make: *** [upload] Error 2
```

After this I ran the command with root privileges and got this.

```
pi@Positron-Pi:~/sketchbook $ sudo make upload
-------------------------
Arduino.mk Configuration:
- [AUTODETECTED]       CURRENT_OS = LINUX 
- [USER]               ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino 
- [COMPUTED]           ARDMK_DIR = /usr/share/arduino (relative to Common.mk)
- [AUTODETECTED]       ARDUINO_VERSION = 105 
- [DEFAULT]            ARCHITECTURE =  
- [DEFAULT]            ARDMK_VENDOR = arduino 
- [DEFAULT]            ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK =  
- [BUNDLED]            AVR_TOOLS_DIR = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr (in Arduino distribution)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDUINO_LIB_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/libraries (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDUINO_VAR_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino//variants (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [COMPUTED]           BOARDS_TXT = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino//boards.txt (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [USER]               USER_LIB_PATH = /home/pi/sketchbook/libraries 
- [DEFAULT]            PRE_BUILD_HOOK = pre-build-hook.sh 
- [USER]               BOARD_TAG = uno 
- [COMPUTED]           CORE = arduino (from build.core)
- [COMPUTED]           VARIANT = standard (from build.variant)
- [COMPUTED]           OBJDIR = build-uno (from BOARD_TAG)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDUINO_CORE_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino//cores/arduino (from ARDUINO_DIR, BOARD_TAG and boards.txt)
- [DETECTED]           MONITOR_BAUDRATE = 9600  (in sketch)
- [DEFAULT]            OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = s 
- [DEFAULT]            MCU_FLAG_NAME = mmcu 
- [DEFAULT]            CFLAGS_STD = -std=gnu11 -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects 
- [DEFAULT]            CXXFLAGS_STD = -std=gnu++11 -fno-threadsafe-statics -flto 
- [COMPUTED]           DEVICE_PATH = /dev/tty* (from MONITOR_PORT)
- [DEFAULT]            FORCE_MONITOR_PORT =  
- [AUTODETECTED]       Size utility: AVR-aware for enhanced output
- [COMPUTED]           BOOTLOADER_PARENT = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino//bootloaders (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDMK_VERSION = 1.5 
- [COMPUTED]           CC_VERSION = 5.4.0 (avr-gcc)
-------------------------
mkdir -p build-uno
make reset
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/sketchbook'
/usr/bin/ard-reset-arduino  /dev/tty36
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ard-reset-arduino", line 46, in <module>
    ser.setDTR(False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 581, in setDTR
    self.dtr = value
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 453, in dtr
    self._update_dtr_state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 614, in _update_dtr_state
    fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIC, TIOCM_DTR_str)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
/usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk:1478: recipe for target 'reset' failed
make[1]: *** [reset] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/sketchbook'
/usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk:1454: recipe for target 'upload' failed
make: *** [upload] Error 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems, that you use the wrong serial port. Is your Arduino really connected to /dev/tty36? If yes, then you don't have the correct permission to access it. Check, which group the device has and be sure, that your user is part of this group

Comment: How would I check which group I am in, as well as the permissions I possess?

Comment: The command `id` will show the groups of the current user. with `ls -l /dev/tty36` you can check the permissions and the group of the device.

Comment: /dev/tty36 is a root directory and the current user is in the group "27(sudo)"